# Send Multiple Invites with sipsak

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm trying to diagnose an issue with my asterisk server.
It occurs when INVITEs are sent simultaneously to the server.

I've got the following sipsak command but it only sends one invite, and when I run it multiple times for a bash script, it doesn't seem to have the intended effect.

```
sipsak --from sip:peer1@127.0.0.1 --auth-username peer1 -v --password 1234 --sip-uri sip:peer1@127.0.0.1 -f testdial1
```

How can I get sipsak to send multiple invites in one go?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortanly really "simultaneously" UDP packets not posible things in linux network stack. They will go one after other anyway.

You can do multiple "calls" using sipp.

```
sipp -sn uac -d 20000 -s 2005 IP.OF.YOUR.BOX -l 30
```

This command will connect as a client, and give the duration of the call 20K miliseconds (or 20 seconds), will dial the server at ip IP.OF.YOUR.BOX, and try to reach the extension 2005, with a limit of 30 simultaneous calls